# Memory error when initializes a large numpy array in a function

Tags: python, arrays, linux, python-2.7, numpy

I have encountered a memory error problem while initializing a large numpy array in a function.

While I tried to initialize the same in main function, it works and even when I used it in IPython (python terminal) it works.

```
Stacks = np.zeros((448,448,40,120))
```

Also tried with np.empty()

Anyway while doing the same thing in

```
def func(arr):
   Stacks = np.zeros((448,448,40,120))

func (arr)
```

`arr` is an array of size (448, 448, 4800).

Just wanted to save this 3D array into 4D one. But it shows memory error in the function call.

The system has at least 4GB RAM. I don't think RAM is a bottleneck because it is working from main as well as Python terminal.

Comment: The array you're trying to create takes almost 8 gigabytes. Same with the `arr` array you already have, assuming the dtypes match. You don't seem to have a clear understanding of how much memory you're trying to use.

Comment: If you just want to reshape `arr`, you can take a reshaped view with `numpy.reshape`, without needing to allocate another 8 gigabytes.

Comment: U r absolutely right. But it is not clear why it is working in main. Even if I have initialized two different array of same size (7.17gb * 2), it is working. And also in python terminal that is working. Any idea why?